# Is a 4p4c rj22 plug physically compatable with a 6p6c jack?

Tags: cables

cant seem to find any decent panel mount rj22 jacks but rj12 looks pretty close, and I cant help but wonder if it will fit.

Comment: That depends on the topology of how you wire it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An RJ-22 plug will fit into a RJ-11 or RJ-12 socket but the RJ-22 plug is much more narrow than the RJ-11 /RJ-12 plugs. This will lead to an unreliable connection because the wire pins in the socket will be bent as the plug is twisted sideways.

As a person who works with these connectors regularly, I would assume that a RJ-12 socket would be used only for a RJ-11 or RJ-12 plug and never plug a RJ-22 plug into it.

In other words, I think that using a RJ-12 socket for a RJ-22 plug is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

RJ11 (6 position, 4 contact) connectors, and RJ12 (6 position, 6 contact) connectors and the RJ22 (4 position, 4 contact) connectors are used for telephone and data applications with centre pair then outer wires for next pair.

The P/J’s are mechanically compatible. Some are designed for solid IDC crimp and others for stranded wire.

But for Ethernet twisted pair, UTP or STP, on R45 May be wired for either way depending CAT5/6

Comment: Re Ethernet paoring: 2nd pair is NOT adjacent pins!

Comment: That depends but actually refers to RJ45 so I will edit to avoid the confusion https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU5Su.jpg